# Avoid compiler errors in externs (closure compiler)

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Closure Compiler can be configured to promote selected types of warnings to errors. This is helpful when a development team wants to hold their JS to a stricter standard. However, I am running into an issue where a number of libraries we rely on (such as RequireJS) are not quite as strict. So when I do this:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js input.js
                       --compilation_level ADVANCED_COMPILATION 
                       --externs require.js
                       --jscomp_error=missingProperties
```

The build fails on missing property errors in RequireJS. Of course, without the error escalation, the build succeeds.

In the case of Require, there are so few public symbols that it's trivial to create a faux externs file instead of using the real thing. But that doesn't scale - we use myriad other libraries that would all need to have separate externs contracts maintained.

I see two possible solutions, but don't have enough info to execute either one. Either (1) get Closure to fall back to the normal warning configuration for externs; or (2) use a tool that can reliably/consistently extract an externs contract for a given library. Or any other solutions I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create extern files, not use the original source.  Using the original source only works for very simple libraries.  I know there have been a couple of tools to extract externs but they don't provide type information.   Generally, you want to ask the library maintainers for something, then ask the Closure Compiler mailing list, and then build something yourself (and share it).

Comment: This is the answer I was afraid of. Most libraries do not maintain an externs file, and it is not practical for us to do so internally. But thanks for validating the "correct" position on this issue.

Comment: Whether an extern file is available for a library is a major factor in the decision of which compilation level to use. See http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html